# How i can generate number of rows, columns in table using perl loop in mojolicious?

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I have a task in **mojolicious**, i must pass to a **template folder** the number of rows in html table, in template folder, based on the number of rows, it must generate the necessary amount of rows that i ask, to do it i must use loops. The idea is, i write the number of roes that i want, for example 3, submit, and then the program generates me the correct amount that i want. May be i should use hashes?

My controller:

`my @rownum = (1,2,3,4,5);`

`$self->render("table/tablerow", rownum => \@rownum);`

and this is the code in template.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
TABLE {
 border-collapse: collapse;  
}
TD, TH {
 padding: 10px; 
 border: 1px solid black; 
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What template system? [ep](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Rendering#Embedded-Perl)?

Comment: Yes, exactly , i want to write perl code there by ep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a [Mojo::Template](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojo/Template). I pass the rows in a variable, and I don't care what the count is. Inside the template I simply output something for each element in the list:

```
use v5.10;
use Mojo::Template;

my @rows = (1,2,3,4,5);

my $mt = Mojo::Template->new;
say $mt->vars(1)->render(<<'EOF', { rows => \@rows } );
% for (@$rows) {
<%= "Row $_\n" =%>
% }
EOF
```

There are plenty of other ways to do this with Mojo::Template, too.

Answer (score 2):

Since's you've passed the reference of `@rownum` to your template, it's available directly in the template. You can then embed a Perl loop in your template and iterate over the dereferenced array.

```
<table>
   <tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr>
   % for my $n (@$rownum) {
   <tr><td>Cell <%= $n %></td><td><%= $n %></td></tr>
   % }
</table>
```

Which will generate this table

```
<table>
   <tr><th>Heading 1</th><th>Heading 2</th></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>1</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 2</td><td>2</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 3</td><td>3</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 4</td><td>4</td></tr>
   <tr><td>Cell 5</td><td>5</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers, here is also my solution.
My controller and param:

`my $rownum= $self->param('rownumber'); print $rownum; $self->render('table/tablerow', 'rownumber' => $rownum,);`

And my loop in the template that is html.ep
`%foreach (1..$rownumber) { <tr> <th> <%=  $_ %> </th> <td> <%=  $_ %> </td> </tr> % }`